# How can I use nginx to improve nodejs performance

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx

I am learning how to build up web front-end and backend by myself.
I have read some blogs about using nginx to improve nodejs performance.
But I still have some question , I hope some people could help me!

Serve static  file
1. I wana build up a pure doc web(like [pebble time dev doc](https://developer.pebble.com/docs/android/)). My plan is using angularjs. Each time user click one item, using ajax to load the specific html   resource. As far as I know, Nginx could server static files very well. Can I use Nginx and no nodejs backend here?

2.Build up normal web , including sign in , sign out , session and so on. Some people said that it is really bad to serve and render page by nodejs itself. However, I should check session in each user request. Is it any possible that nodejs check session and then nginx response html file?
(Front-end is angularjs also.)
such as

```
app.get('/about', function (req, res)
{
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
    response.write(html);  // serve by nginx
    response.end();  
});
```

Comment: it's same thing to tell nginx to do like this: location / { try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ $uri.php; index index.html index.htm index.php; }

Comment: sorry , @num8er . I update the sample code.

Comment: Yes, that's fine. But I hope You've used example in my answer. About sessions: is just an object in req.session. So You can have middleware where You check req.session for existence of user session or role and if it's OK You call next(). Better watch in "middleware expressjs" in Youtube

Comment: @num8er , thanks a lot! I will try it.

Comment: I do just api, with auth, deauth routes where I get token in json. And in every request from angular, react and etc. app I put token in params or headers and check in backend if data behind this token and then if it's OK, passing request to route handler, otherwise just  respond with unauthorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be straight.

Better practice to have folder where You have nodejs app with public folder, and tell nginx to look only to public folder for some extensions, but for other requests to pass to nodejs

You nginx host file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

    index index.html index.htm;

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|js|flv|swf|html|htm|mp3)$ {
        root /home/yourdomain/public; # or any path to public folder
        expires 30d;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    # all other requests goes to :8000
    location / {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Have folder structure similar to this

[image]

Comment: so server.js listen on 8000 port in your example, right?

Comment: @鄭元傑 NodeJS listens at 8000 (in most cases 1337)or any port You want, nginx listens at 80 and proxy passes to Your node apps port